# Are conditional includes in Moodle possible?

Tags: php, moodle

In Moodle, Is there a way to conditionally include a file depending on what course is being displayed? Is there any other php workaround to conditionally including files in Moodle?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is edit my incourse.php custom theme layout to conditonally include different files based on what course or page is being displayed.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup its possible, heres an example using the classes added to the body on page load:

```
   <?php
        if ($PAGE->bodyid == "page-site-index") {
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/hero.php');
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/certificate_logos.php');
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: but $PAGE->bodyid is intented to be css body ID instead of course identifier, you really should use if ($COURSE->id == SITEID) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, moodle has a global variable $COURSE, you can check get realtime course info from this object in theme files, then decide what to include.

Comment: @LesBallard if ($COURSE->id == SITEID) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at course formats - these are the defaults

http://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Course_formats

But you can develop your own course formats too.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_formats

So you can include different files for different courses.